# AngularJS Ionic ng-repeat. Create new list item with only services in active state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a shopping cart for my Ionic app and have most figured out except for the running itemized total. I have my array items defaulted to active:false and when clicked they become active:true and their price value is added to the running total. However I would also like to have an itemized list available with the name of the product..I added a new function which will hold the active services along with their price values.. The problem arises when i try to have each item on its own line using ng-repeat.. below is the corresponding code snippets. I know It's something basic I'm missing so please take a look.. Thanks

```
<ion-view view-title="Shop" ng-controller="OrderFormController">
<ion-content>

    <div class="card">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="service in services">
            {{totalDetail()}}
        </ion-item>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="service in services">
            {{service.name}}
                <button class="button button-outline button-small button-stable" ng-click="toggleActive(service)" ng-class="{active:service.active}">
                    {{service.price | currency}}
                </button>
        </ion-item>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <ion-item>
            <!-- Calculate the total price of all chosen services. Format it as currency. -->
            Total: {{total() | currency}}
        </ion-item>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

```
myApp.controller('OrderFormController', function($scope) {

// Define the model properties. The view will loop
// through the services array and genreate a li
// element for every one of its items.

$scope.services = [
    {
        name: 'Espresso',
        price: 27,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Americano',
        price: 36,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Macchiato',
        price: 57,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Cappuccino',
        price: 42,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Mocha',
        price: 55,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Latte',
        price: 39,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Chai Latte',
        price: 50,
        active:false
    }
];

$scope.toggleActive = function(s){
    s.active = !s.active;
};

// Helper method for calculating the total price

$scope.total = function(){

    var total = 0;

    // Use the angular forEach helper method to
    // loop through the services array:

    angular.forEach($scope.services, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            total+= s.price;
        }
    });

    return total;
};

$scope.totalDetail = function(){

    var totalDetail = "";

    // Use the angular forEach helper method to
    // loop through the services array:

    angular.forEach($scope.services, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            totalDetail+= s.name+" $"+s.price+".00 ";

        }
    });

    return totalDetail;
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. Not sure if its the best way to go about it but it works..

```
ng-repeat="service in services | filter:true"
```

hopefully that helps someone else